# Add quotes at the beginning and end of each line - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What is the best way to add quotes (Double quotes) at the beginning and end of each line using Visual Studio.

The following works but it adds quotes for each word. Is there a solution for each line?

[image]

Comment: Search for `([^\r\n]*)(\r|\n)*` and replace it with `"$1"$2`. First capture group is the text on each line (any character except the new line/carriage return characters). Second capture group is the line break. Add quotes around the first group, then return both. Note that this will eat empty lines. If you know the line break sequence your file uses, you can modify the second capture group to avoid removing empty lines, though you will have to consider if you want quotes around them or not.

Comment: Here's a version that will quote (but not eat) empty lines: `([^\r\n]*)(\r?\n)?`. And a version that will not quote (or eat) empty lines: `([^\r\n]+)(\r?\n)?`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please post this as answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

We can quote an entire line by splitting on [line breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). For most modern operating systems, that means looking for `\n` (Linux, MacOS) or `\r\n` (Windows).

For our purposes, the text in the current line can include any characters except `\r` and `\n`. The corresponding [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) would be:

```
[^\r\n]
```

Since we want to wrap the whole line, we accept zero or more characters in this set:

```
[^\r\n]*
```

Then we match the line break:

```
[^\r\n]*(\r?\n)
```

Since the last line will not have a line break (or else it wouldn't be the last line), we make the capture optional:

```
[^\r\n]*(\r?\n)?
```

In order to replace the text with a quoted copy, we add a capture group around our character set:

```
([^\r\n]*)(\r?\n)?
```

And use the [Find and Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019) tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) with [regular expressions turned on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to replace our selection with the first capture group (`$1`) wrapped in quotes and followed by the line break in the second capture group (`$2`).

```
"$1"$2
```